# Solving $\sin x\cos5x=\sin ax\cos3x$ without many addition formulas

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am trying to solve this trigonometric equation (with $a$ a constant)
$$\sin(x)\cos(5x)=\sin(ax)\cos(3x)$$
I tried expanding all terms using angle addition, but I got a huge Left and Right hand sides, and apart from the obvious $x=0$ solution,  I can't find the rest.

Is there an easy way to solve this? Or is it necessary to do the huge procedure?

Comment: Depending on $a$, the solutions will vary. I do not think there is an easy way to solve this if $a$ is irrational.

Comment: [This](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ysqe4bwpkb) graph might be useful

Comment: Look at my comment to @Math.

Answer (score 3):

Consider that you look for the zero's of function
$$f(a,x)=\sin(x)\cos(5x)-\sin(ax)\cos(3x)$$ Since $f(a,x)+f(a,-x)=0$, we only care about the positive values of $x$. The linked [coutour plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContourPlot%5B++Sin%5Bx%5D+Cos%5B5+x%5D+%3D%3D+Sin%5Ba+x%5D+Cos%5B3+x%5D%2C+%7Ba%2C+-2+Pi%2C+2+Pi%7D%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C+10%7D%5D) reveals the complexity of the problem (the same was noticed in @DatBoi's plot).

Excluding the trivial solution $x=0$, there are a few interesting observations

- for any value of $a$, $f\left(a,(2 k+1)\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=0$
- for any value of $a$, $f\left(a,k \pi\right)=(-1)^{k-1} \sin(a \pi)$ which would be $0$ every time $a$ will be an integer. The same would happen every time $\sin \left(\frac{\pi  k}{a}\right)=0$ or $\cos \left(\frac{5\pi  k}{a}\right)=0$.

As you may see, the situation is quite complex.

Taking into account the fact that $f(a,0)=0$ and $f\left(a,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=0$, in that range there are one (if $a\geq 1$) or two (if $a\lt 1$) other solutions.

If $a<1$ we could perform a Taylor expansion around $x=0$ and have
$$\frac{f(a,x)} x=(1-a)+\frac{a^3+27 a-76}{6} x^2-\frac{a^5+90 a^3+405
   a-3376}{120} x^4+O\left(x^6\right)$$

Using the first term only, this would give as an *estimate*
$$x_{(1)}=\sqrt{\frac{6(1-a) }{76-27 a-a^3}}$$
Using the first and second terms, we need to solve a quadratic in $x^2$ (keep the $+\Delta$ solution) and this gives $x_{(2)}$ (it is too long to type but simple) (do not use it if $a<-2.724$ since it will make the estimate to be a complex number) .

Just a few results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
a & x_{(1)} & x_{(2)} & \text{solution} \\
 +0.75 & 0.164654 & 0.171746 &  0.171508 \\
 +0.50 & 0.219308 & 0.236777 &  0.235572 \\
 +0.25 & 0.254944 & 0.283201 &  0.280237 \\
 +0.00 & 0.280976 & 0.319532 &  0.314159 \\
 -0.25 & 0.301027 & 0.348980 &  0.340785 \\
 -0.50 & 0.316889 & 0.373166 &  0.361993 \\
 -0.75 & 0.329568 & 0.393117 &  0.379004 \\
 -1.00 & 0.339683 & 0.409633 &  0.392699 \\
 -1.25 & 0.347644 & 0.423424 &  0.403741 \\
 -1.50 & 0.353738 & 0.435171 &  0.412640 \\
 -1.75 & 0.358184 & 0.445565 &  0.419791 \\
 -2.00 & 0.361158 & 0.455386 &  0.425501
\end{array}
\right)$$

Now, to polish the root, start with one of these estimates and use Newton method. For example, using $a=-2.345$, the iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.470197 \\
 1 & 0.432769 \\
 2 & 0.431443 \\
 3 & 0.431440 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

I hope that you see the complexity of the problem. I suppose that it could become simpler only for integer values of $a$.

**Edit**

For the fun of it, I have been able to generate a still better estimate for the case where $a<1$. It writes
$$x_{(3)}=\sqrt{\frac{60 (a-1) \left(a^3+27 a-76\right)}{7 a^6+3 a^5+270 a^4-1250 a^3+6075
   a^2-29697 a+47632}   }$$